# How do you set an auth header on an image in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have images in my react-native application that require authentication.  I have a token that I add to all of my server calls but I don't know how to set it for an Image.  Can I override the loading calling for an image?  Do I have to preload the image using fetch and then provide the result to the Image component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'http://...', headers: {} }} />
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Was that option documented somewhere?